# How to obtain this $R[\sqrt d] \cong R[x]/(x^2-d)$ isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, direct-sum

I'm trying to obtain this $R[\sqrt d] \cong R[x]/(x^2-d)$ *isomorphism*.

I was thinking about using the **Chinese remainder theorem** to obtain this *isomorphism* (maybe I have a mistake there):  $R[\sqrt d] \cong R[x]/(x^2-d) \cong R[x]/(x-\sqrt d) \oplus R[x]/(x+ \sqrt d)$.

But I can't get it from here.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $d$ is a perfect square in $R$, the claim is false, because by the Chinese remainder theorem you get the decomposition you said, and $R[x]/(x-\sqrt d)\oplus R[x]/(x+\sqrt d)\cong R\times R$. While, on the other hand, $R\left[\sqrt d\right]=R\not\cong R\times R$  (in general). In fact, for fields, you have that isomorphism ony if you can't use Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli well, this is embarassing

Comment: Also, for a general ring where $d\ne\alpha^2$, it is not too clear what $\sqrt d$ is. To be more precise, in that case we could arguably take $R[x]/(x^2-d)$ as the general definition of $R[\sqrt d]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see that $R[\sqrt{d}] = \{a + b \sqrt{d}: a, b \in R\}$. Now, if $p(\sqrt{d}) + \langle x^2 - d \rangle \in R[x]/\langle x^2 - d \rangle$ then we always have an expression $p(\sqrt{d}) + \langle x^2 - d \rangle = r(\sqrt{d}) + \langle x^2 - d \rangle$ where $r(x)$ is in reduced form (divide $p(x)$ by $x^2 - d$ and then $r(x)$ is just the remainder). The isomorphism is given by the correspondence $r(\sqrt{d}) \leftrightarrow r(\sqrt{d}) + \langle x^2 - d \rangle$

Just out of interest, what is $R$ in your example? I think it needs to be (at least) an integral domain for this to work.

AND: as the commenter pointed out, $x^2 - d$ must be irreducible over $R$.

Comment: It is only said that $R$ is a commutative associative ring with $1$

Comment: Maybe it still works at that level of generality. I haven't really thought about it.